# Java auto-intalize primitive variables in Java 8

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm trying to learn Java 8 (moving from C -> Java).  I tried:

```
public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args){
       int i;
       System.out.println(i);
       }
}
```

Gives a compiler error saying the variable "i" has not been initialized.  I thought that one of the nice things about Java was that it would auto-initialize primitives to a default value.

Comment: Nope. You must assign values to local variable before deferencing.

Comment: "it would auto-initialize primitives to a default value" that happens for class fields, not for local variables.